# How to get tracks from Trackmania Original to Trackmania United Forever

Tags: trackmania-forever, trackmania-series

I have played Trackmania Original before and I liked its puzzle campaign a lot. Now I had bought Trackmania United Forever Star Edition from steam, hoping I will be able to play the same puzzles again. I have read many times this Steam edition contains all content from previous versions, however the puzzles present there seem to be very limited, there are only about 30 of them (of 5 tracks of White, Green, Blue, and Red, and 1 Black) and they are not the ones I liked before (with Desert or Alpine setting). I still have the old Trackmania Original archived, but I do not want to use it because it contains StarForce copy protection, which seems incompatible with Windows 7 64b OS I use now - and even if I could fix or cirumvent StarForce, still it would be nice to play the puzzle in the new engine, not only because of better looks, but also because of improved controller support.

Is there any way how to copy the puzzle tracks from Original to United Forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial solution, which adds the challenges, but not as a campaign: the puzzles can be downloaded from [Nadeo Tracks at United TMX](http://original.tm-exchange.com/?action=tracksearch&mode=1&id=511), with custom search for Track Name `TMO` and Type `Puzzle`.

Downloaded tracks can be placed in the `Challenges` folder (`%userprofile%\Documents\TrackMania\Tracks\Challenges`) and then browsed for and played one by one.

One can then build a custom campaign from those tracks, given you have already earned enough coppers (510 coppers are needed to add all 51 Trackmania Original tracks).